# Criterion for representation-finite algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A=KQ/I$ a quiver algebra with acyclic $Q$.

> Question: Is $A$ representation-finite if and only if $\tau^{-n}(A)=0$ for some $n \geq 1$?

Here $\tau$ is the Auslander-Reiten translate of $A$.

This is true if $A$ is hereditary or more generally $A$ has a postprojective component. Does it hold more generally?